# What means this error?

Tags: transactions, rpc, operation, error, transfer

When I want validate my offline generated transaction using RPC call `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_operation`.

I got error:

```
Json_encoding.Unexpected_field(\"protocol\")
```

My generated transaction (keys and addresses are hidden):

```
{ branch: 'BM3ETw1z6rrrqGjfLUvk2auYodzn8P2AGSSuBaWwHttc2oi7zsV',
  contents:
   [ { kind: 'transaction',
       fee: '2000',
       gas_limit: '10600',
       storage_limit: '300',
       amount: '100',
       destination: '',
       source: '',
       counter: '' } ],
  protocol: 'Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd',
  signature:
   '' }
```

But if I broadcast this transaction to blockchain it does works

Comment: the error means that the json you generated does not satisfy the grammar of the rpc endpoint you are using. As you can see here it seems you need to use the field `protocol_hash` https://tezos.gitlab.io/tezos/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-scripts-run-operation

What this means is that there is probably a difference between the version of the protocol you used for generating the json and the one you use in your node currently

Comment: I've been having a similar problem. Did you manage to get the issue resolved? I keep getting a 400 error but no idea why. I'm working on [a Tezos client library](https://github.com/roppa/tezmania/blob/e857091966b29312243e7773852cd1bf0648c5fb/src/network/network.ts#L124) for learning purposes.